# How to modify post_install hook ? Specifying multiple `post_install` hooks is unsupported

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podfile, post-install

I am new to iOS development and tried to merge the following pieces of code into one post_install hook without luck:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      target.build_settings(config.name)['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end

post_install do |pi|
  t = pi.pods_project.targets.find { |t| t.name == 'MyPod' }
  t.build_configurations.each do |bc|
    bc.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end
end
```

**How do I turn this into one post_install hook ?**
I did not find a solution for declaring multiple variables and haven't quite figured out how the syntax really works.

I'd really appreciate a hint.

**error message**

```
Specifying multiple `post_install` hooks is unsupported.
```

Best regards!

Comment: I have the same question. Have you figured it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I ended up changing the deployment target in X Code only and it worked eventually.  It's a pain to set up though.

Comment: In my case, there are 2 `post_install do |installer|` and what I did is to put. 2 into one .